# Oracle SQL Plus Reduce fundamentally equal rows into one row

Tags: sql, oracle

Apologies if asked and answered, I was not able to find a similar solution.

I have a table

```
+---------+---------+---------+
| column1 | column2 | column3 |
+---------+---------+---------+
| valA    | valB    | valC    |
+---------+---------+---------+
| valA    | valB    | valD    |
+---------+---------+---------+
```

I need to write a query that identifies this conflict between these two rows and prints out col 1, col2, col3 valC, col3 valD.

What I've tried is

```
select distinct t1.column1, t1.column2, t1.column3, t2.column3
from table t1 inner join table t2 on t1.column2 = t2.column2
where t1.column1 = t2.column2
and t1.column3 <> t2.column3
```

Resulting in the following

```
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| column1 | column2 | column3 | column4 |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| valA    | valB    | valC    | valD    |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| valA    | valB    | valD    | valC    |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

The second row is fundamentally identical to the first, and is therefore, redundant and I'd like to prevent it from showing.

Comment: There is no COLUMN4 in your query.  ???

Comment: @BobJarvis col4 is t2.col3 just missing an AS alias spec

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach would work fine, but you just need `<`:

```
select distinct t1.column1, t1.column2, t1.column3, t2.column3
from table t1 inner join
     table t2
     on t1.column1 = t2.column1 and
        t1.column2 = t2.column2 and
        t1.column3 < t2.column3;
```

Note that this fixes the column comparisons in your code.

However, I might be more inclined to use aggregation:

```
select column1, column2,
       listagg(column3, ',') within group (order by column3) as column3s
from table t
group by column1, column2
having min(column3) <> max(column3);
```

Answer (score 1):

So you wish to compare if the column3 is different for the group of records in(col1,col2).

```
select col1,col2,max(col3),min(col3)
 from table
group by col1,col2
having max(col3) <> min(col3)
```

Comment: what if there are more than two possible values for `col3`?

Comment: The query would need to be modified. Here the OP i understand is looking to see the differing one value

Comment: @GeorgeJoseph This solution works, but I'm choosing the other in that it is more obvious to me what its doing and how it works.